# SpriteKit Unwrapping Optional Error (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, option-type, exc-bad-instruction

Whenever I run my project, I get a bad instruction error on the line...

```
ground.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
```

Here is the full code I am running to go with this snippet. I'm not sure what is happening and I don't have a lot of experience with optionals.

Code:

```
var ground = SKSpriteNode()
ground.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 30))
let groundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Red.png")
ground = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundTexture)
ground.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
ground.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

ground.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
ground.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
ground.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
self.addChild(ground)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are **re initialising** `ground` after creating its physics body and hence the new object does not have physics body thus showing the nil error.

Change your code to

```
let groundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Red.png")
var ground = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundTexture)
ground.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 30))
ground.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
ground.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

ground.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
ground.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
ground.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
self.addChild(ground)
```

As per the comment, general practice when you face the error of **found nil when unwrapping optionals** is to use either `?` or a `if let` to safely un wrap. In this scenario it can be implemented like

```
if let physicsBodyObject = ground.physicsBody {
    physicsBodyObject.dynamic = false
    physicsBodyObject.allowsRotation = false
    //other code
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but  I would suggest you make some slight tweaks for future readers. To avoid crashes in the first place you should replace all the ! with ? whenever possible. Not the best practice to force unwrap even though you know the physics body is there.

Comment: Or even better, just create the physics body separately, then assign it to the node when done configuring it.